# How to vertically align the text in static text box in PowerBuilder?

Tags: text, alignment, vertical-alignment, powerbuilder

How to vertically align the text in static text box in PowerBuilder like the following picture? It can be aligned horizontally to left, center, right. But cannot do the same thing vertically.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You did not provided the PB version and kind (classic /.net if greater than 11)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it cannot be done out of the box.

I have made it anyway "by hand" with the help of the windows API: `DrawText()`, `OffsetRect()` and so on to create an improved rounded command button.

You can look at the code in [that gist](https://gist.github.com/sebkirche/7942101) (look at the `of_drawtext()` method).

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the purpose of this text box?

Maybe you could use another object where you can easily move your text within.

The text in the box may have a variable number of line?

Do you use sql on the window object? 
Maybe put this text between line feed in compute field within the datawindow you used can help you.(Handy Manny's style.....i agree....).

Erf....Seki answered faster

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DW to vertically align a text.

An attribute of the dw static text called "font.escapement" sets the angle at which you want your text displayed.

To display text vertically, set the escapement attribute to 900 (10 * the angle) or to 2700.

Please notice that you will not see the effect in the datawindow painter, you'll have to preview your dw to see if the text is in the correct angle.